# Generic method to print an generic array with lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

```
public static void PrintArray<T> (T[] array)
   => Array.ForEach(array, Console.WriteLine);
```

This code doens't work because Console.Writeline don't have an overload for parameter T or am I misundertanding it?

Comment: This seems like an odd quirk of the method group to delegate conversion overload resolution. The lambda `x => Console.Writeline(x)` works fine. Adding the generic constraint `where T : class` will also allow compilation with the method group. Good question, hopefully someone more knowledgeable will be able to weigh in on why this won't compile as is.

Comment: A better option is `x => Console.WriteLine(x.ToString())`  to avoid possible boxing of value types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

T is a bit too generic in this case, so `Console.WriteLine` does not know how to handle it, as the chosen overload of `Console.WriteLine` depends on the type of T.

`T : class` would use a different overload than `T : struct`.

There are a couple of tricks in this case:

1. Be more explicit:

```
private void Print<T>(T[] arr) =>
    Array.ForEach(arr, x=> Console.WriteLine(x));
```

2. Use a constraint:

```
private void Print<T>(T[] arr) where T : class =>
    Array.ForEach(arr, Console.WriteLine);
```

Comment: using the constraint `T : struct` will not compile because it still will not know which overload to use since there is one for most value types, but it would have to rely on boxing custom structs.

Comment: A struct constraint will also have this issue, so I'm assuming that the lambda example allows for an implicit conversion to object through boxing that method group resolution does not.

Comment: This is more expanded answer than mine, I'll leave mine though

Comment: @JonathonChase I agree with you. But I still cannot understand why `private void Print<T>(T[] arr) where T : IUser => Array.ForEach(arr, Console.WriteLine);` does not work. I would expect that a constraint on an interface would be more restrictive than `class` and thus should work as well.

Comment: @AlvinSartor structs can implement interfaces, so it's not quite as restrictive as you think.

Comment: @JonathonChase wow, I never knew that structs could implement interfaces. I guess that it is not something you see often.

Answer (score -3):

`Array.ForEach()` accepts delegate Action as a second parameter, so if you will change it to

```
public static void PrintArray<T>(T[] array) => Array.ForEach(array, a => Console.WriteLine(a));
```

it should work

Comment: This explanation isn't right but the code is. `Console.WriteLine` is already an `Action`; try running the code `Action<object> writeLine = Console.WriteLine;` it compiles

Comment: @user1538301 I think the problem is that compiler doesn't know the actual type of T and can't select appropriate overload of method, if we manually specify T as object it will compile.

Comment: @ViacheslavYankov That's exactly the problem.

Comment: updated the answer to reflect what I meant. Error was not in first lambda, but in Array.ForEach's method's param